# Is the domain and codomain of composite function a definition or a corollary

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given two functions $f: B \to C$ and $g: A \to B$, the composite function $f \circ g: A \to C$ is defined by $f \circ g (x) = f(g(x))$.

So, is the domain and codomain of $f \circ g$ ($A \to C$) a part of a definition of $f \circ g$, or is it a corollary from the definition $(f \circ g) (x) = f(g(x))$?

Comment: Note that you got the composition order (or the domains) backwards! "$f(g(x))$" doesn't make sense with the given domains, because $g(x)$ is in $C$. You can only have $g(f(x))$ and therefore $g\circ f: A\to C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally, they are a part of definition. A function $f \colon A \to B$ is a correspondence $((A,B),R)$ where $R$ is its single-valued relation(or graph). But a function is usually identical with its relation, and by abuse of notation, one use the same symbol if there is no risk of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Given fully-specified $f$ and $g,$ the domain and codomain of $f\circ g$ can be inferred; that is, no additional definition is required. In other words, the domain and codomain of $f\circ g$ is part of the definition of function composition.